# How to await a method in another prism module?

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

I have been having a play with prism and decided to convert an application to a modular prism application using Prism + WPf + Unity.

This application talks to various bits of hardware so the first thing was to put all my hardware classes into separate modules.

Taking my camera class as an example which talks to a camera system via Ethernet.

Lets say my camera class is like this (before PRISM conversion)

```
Public Class Camera
{
    // bunch of properties 

    public Task<bool> TakePhoto()
    {
       return Task.Run(()=>
       {
          // ...
          // Do taking photo stuff
          // ...    
          return CameraPhotoTakenResult; // Return result of taking photo 
       });
    }
}
```

Before `PRISM` conversion I call the `TakePhoto method` like so

```
var TakePhoto = MyCamera.TakePhoto();

// ...
// Do some stuff and call other methods
// ...  

var result = await TakePhoto;

// Check the result and do something with it
// ...
// Continue doing other stuff
```

From my understanding, I now have to use the `EventAggregator` to trigger the camera, which is fine, but would this mean I would have to use another Event to send back the result? if so then how can I modify my code to await on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the type as normal. Break out the public interface of the class into a common project which both your hardware module and consumer will reference. Your hardware module registers a class in some kind of Dependency Injection container (my example will use Unity):

```
public class HardwareModule : IModule
{
    IUnityContainer _container;
    public HardwareModule(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _container.RegisterType<ICamera, Camera>();
    }
}
```

Then in the consumer, you obtain an instance from the container and use the object in the normal way.

```
public class HardwareConsumer
{
    IUnityContainer _container;
    public HardwareConsumer(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public async void TakePhoto()
    {
        ICamera camera = _container.Resolve<ICamera>();

        var result = await camera.TakePhoto;
    }
}
```

But since this is using dependency injection to inject the container, if you have no other need for the container, you can also/instead inject the instance into your class:

```
public class HardwareConsumer2
{
    ICamera _camera;
    public HardwareConsumer2(ICamera camera)
    {
        _camera = camera;
    }

    public async void TakePhoto()
    {
        var result = await _camera.TakePhoto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, will give it ago